# Where can I get British Agricultural Field Boundaries as Vector Data?

Tags: data, vector

I am looking for vector data outlining the agricultural field boundaries in the UK (Specifically Scotland, England and Wales). I have tried all sources of open source data I can find and looked at Ordnance Survey Data.

Ordnance Survey have the data however they package it as part of the Vectormap Local data which costs in excess of £800k for the UK. The actual sub layer is called Rural Boundaries when the Shapefile is extracted.

If there is no realistic way of getting this data, or purchasing it for a reasonable price, is there a way to extract the data from aerial photography?

Comment: I can only share my knowledge on how this data is handled in Germany, but - if I get it correctly - you look for property data. This data is - in Germany - protected by several laws and you may only ask the municipalities for access if you have a signed permission from the owner. And then you still have to pay a fee. You could look at the CORINE-landcover-data, if you do not need distinct fields and are not that sensitive to small scales.

Comment: how does £800K compare to the cost of your time digitising aerial photography? You could try a FOI request to the rural payments agencies?

Comment: As to extracting the data from remote sensing data: That's possible, yet still a lot of work. You have to get all the data, then do proper training, ideally for several times of the year, run the classification for all of Britain, verify it, redo it, cry a bit, ... not worth the hassle if you need high quality data in high resolution. As Ian points out, that 800k would be well invested - if you absolutely need the data.

Comment: Aside CORINE, Britain provides vectorized WMS-services on agricultural land use (CROME).

Comment: If you seek open data then the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Local councils may also have datasets they can make available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://agrimetrics.co.uk/data/field-boundaries

AI generated field boundaries for the UK. If you still need them.

Answer (score 2):

This is just for Scotland, but are either of these you're looking for?

- https://data.gov.uk/dataset/agricultural-parishes
- https://data.gov.uk/dataset/urban-rural-classification-2013-2014

Additionally, an open data portal you may not have tried yet.

- http://naturalengland-defra.opendata.arcgis.com/

If these are not what you're looking for, your best bet may be to contact naturalengland directly to see if they know where you can get your information.

In Canada, farm boundary shapefiles (if they exist) would likely be held by the municipal or possibly provincial governments, the equivalent government in the UK might have similar shapefiles if you are able to contact them. Alternatively, it might be worth contacting the Department for Environment Food & Rural Affairs to see if they have a shapefile that fits your need, and if they do, if they're willing to share.

Comment: Unfortunatly the datasets you mention above are not field boundaries but lots of dimonds showing the landuse generally in each area. Its intresting data though.

Answer (score 0):

I think OS is giving away some of its data now, but its poor vector format.

Looking at my own local area (Somerset) where the historical ownership of land may well differ from other parts of the country, land registry parcels pretty much mark all field (title) boundaries, but not all. Farms here have been broken up from small to large mainly through individual field sales.

Coupled with a land use download from OSM, you could eliminate non agricultural use, and subdivide the larger title plots by differing use.

Finally, last measure.... lidar at 1m DSM will identify hedges and walls if vectorised. Going to take a lot of clean up.....

Good luck.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).